# Swift 2: Call a method after pressing Return in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a Text Field in a Tip Calculator. I want the Tip Calculator to update all the fields of my calculator.

With the current code that I have now, for whatever reason. It doesn't call calcTip() (or atleast it doesn't seem to) until I press return once, enter another (or the same) value and press return again.

I'm really close to having this app work exactly how I want it to, and I feel like I'm just 1 or 2 lines away.

My ViewController conforms to UITextFieldDelegate, and I declared         amountBeforeTaxTextField.delegate = self in viewDidLoad.

TextShouldReturn:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        amountBeforeTaxTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true
        amountBeforeTaxTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        calcTip()
        amountBeforeTaxTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

calcTip():

```
    func calcTip() {
    let tip = tipCalc.calculateTip()
    let total = tipCalc.calculateTotal()
    let tax = tipCalc.calculateTax()
    let perPerson = total / Float(Int(partySizeSlider.value))

    tipCalc.tipPercentage = (tipPercentageSlider.value)
    tipCalc.amountBeforeTax = (amountBeforeTaxTextField.text! as
        NSString).floatValue
    tipCalc.taxPercentage = (taxPercentageSlider.value)
    resultLabel.text = String(format: "Tip $%.2f, Tax: $%.2f Total: $%.2f", tip, tax, total)
    perPersonLabel.text = String(format: "Per-Person Total: $%.2f", perPerson)
}
```

Note: I have the same outcome with & without .becomeFirstResponder()

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What's the point of the `becomeFirstResponder()` and `resignFirstResponder()` calls?

Comment: @AaronBrager resignFirstResponder closes the keyboard when you press enter. Not sure about become.

Comment: Why you want it to `becomeFirstResponder()` and `resignFirstResponder()` right away? shouldn't be `resignFirstResponder()` after you calculate? move `amountBeforeTaxTextField.resignFirstResponder()` to bottom of `calcTip()`

Comment: Is it not placed after I calculate? Nonetheless,  I get the same result when I put resignFirstResponder in the bottom of calcTip(), and I was even unsuccessful when I put resignFirstResponder in a Defer Block.

Answer (score 1):

So your textFieldShouldReturn function is called when you press the bottom right button on the keyboard, which can have various titles; such as "Go", "Return", "Done", or "Send".

Your first line, only accomplishes a UI effect; meaning when the user taps on the textfield to input text, there will be a little box that appears on the far right handside of the textfield that allows the user to clear the inputted text, if there is any. Sort of like a reset.

When you use becomeFirstResponder, you are pretty much calling another keyboard to pop up, so you aren't accomplishing anything by doing that.

When you use resignFirstResponder, you are hiding the keyboard.

What you want to do is remove "becomeFirstResponder" as well as the first line, because those don't do anything to help your problem. That should be the solution to the problem you are facing.

Comment: I understand what the first line does, but I didn't see anywhere else I would put it. Thanks for letting me know about FirstResponder because I didn't know what that does, but even with it removed I still have the same issue. I have to enter the value twice, or 2 different values for my labels to change.

Comment: Put that line of code in viewDidLoad().

i would love to help, but you haven't provided enough code for me to deduce what the problem is. you're only giving me a small bit for a much larger problem.

Comment: When I put it in viewDidLoad() it just made it so that I can't close keyboard. There's nothing more to show though. I need my labels to update like they're supposed to in calcTip.

Comment: What line did you put in viewDidLoad()?

Comment: I put it in the last line.